# How can I make a code that displays buttons on one half of a tkinter frame and a plot on the other half?

Tags: python

I have a code here.

```
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import math
import numpy as np

root = tk.Tk()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
x = np.linspace(3,-3,10000)
p = np.sin(x)
w = np.sin(2*x)
l = np.sin(x)/x
c = np.cos(1/x) 
r = np.tan(x)
ur = np.cos(x)/x
def firstx():
    plt.plot(x, p, 'p-', label = 'y=sin(x)')
    fig.canvas.draw()
def snx():
    plt.plot(x, w, 'c-', label = 'y=sin(2x)')
    fig.canvas.draw()
def thx():
    plt.plot(x, l, 'm-', label = 'y=sin(x)/x')
    fig.canvas.draw()
def fthx():
    plt.plot(x, c, 'v-', label = 'y=sin(1/x)')
    fig.canvas.draw()
def tan():
    plt.plot(x, r, 's-', label = 'y=tan(x)')
    ax.set_ylim([-5, 5])
    fig.canvas.draw()

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
plot_widget = canvas.get_tk_widget()

plot_widget.grid(row=0, column=1)

tk.Button(root, text="y=sin(x)", command=firstx).grid(row=0, column=0)
tk.Button(root, text="y=sin(2x)", command=snx).grid(row=1, column=0)
tk.Button(root, text="y=sin(x)/x", command=thx).grid(row=2, column=0)
tk.Button(root, text="y=sin(1/x)", command=fthx).grid(row=3, column=0)
tk.Button(root, text="y=tan(x)", command=tan).grid(row=4, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

If you run the code you will see one button on the left and the rest of the buttons on the bottom left. How do I make it so that the buttons are all on the left and not the bottom left?

P.S. I am using python 3.6.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
plot_widget.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

to

```
plot_widget.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=5)
```

Read about the rowspan= argument here https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/grid.html or https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm

Comment: This answer was super useful! I'll upvote as soon as I build up my reputation.